# SMS/USSD Content Retrieval

Tags: database, mobile, sms, ussd

Hi guys 
I'm working on this project where I'll need to retrieve information from a database through sms/ussd, much like how you would check you credit on you mobile phone.
Would appreciate any help to head me in the right direction.
(Hope I put my question out clearly, if not ask me so I can clarify)

Answer (score 1):

I can help you extensively in solving your problem. As far as I got understood what you want to achieve is, perhaps that when a SMS message comes to your GSM Modem or GSM Phone, your software should be capable enough to interpret that message according to your protocol and should respond accordingly, also when it needs to process database. This is absolutely possible. Let me describe it in brief. Following are the general steps:

1. You must connect your GSM Phone or Modem through your software with a particular COM port.
2. After assigning and configuring the port, You issue `AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0,0` command to Modem, if it responds to `OK`, then it indicates that it supports this command, else an error is generated.
3. Now send an SMS from some other phone, you will see that the SMS directly goes to your software, now you can process it as per your needs.

The whole process is slightly a lengthy description, but it is possible.